# Context menu on extended LinearLayout view

Tags: android, contextmenu

I've a class (a view) that extends LinearLayout.

Now, I'm trying to do a context menu for each element of that class in my activity, but there's no way, it never fires:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    MyLinearLayout[] arrayLayout = new MyLinearLayout[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLayout.length; i++)
    {
       //I ve removed code that fill the array and do some actions


       //and then:
       ll.addView(arrayLayout[i]);
       registerForContextMenu(arrayLayout[i]);
    }
    setContentView(ll);
}

@Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "context menu");
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, R.string.CTX_EDIT);
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, R.string.CTX_ELIM);
    }
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    function1(item.getItemId());

return true;
}

public void function1(int id){
    Toast.makeText(this, "function 1 called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The context menu never shows, i've read a lot problems about it, and i think this is because of the LinearLayout extended class, but I'm sure there is a way to do this, or i'm missing something. Can anyone help, please? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an empty array of MyLinearLayout: `arrayLayout = new MyLinearLayout[num]`,

Then you are trying to set a context menu with:

```
registerForContextMenu(arrayLayout[i])
```

Which does nothing since `arrayLayout[i]` is `null`.

Comment: No, maybe i didnt explained well. I've edited the code, where i had "//fill the array and do some actions" i removed some code of filling the array and creating some info for that element. Anyway, in the activity, when testing, it show the elements, but the context menu never fires.